# ASP.Net Load Data from another page

Tags: asp.net

i am facing one problem..

I have a page which has some templates related to user..

User use this template to send email..

User can have option to save this template and then he can load the saved templates...

What i want is on click on "Load Template" link. a new page appears which will display all the saved templates for logged in user. this page can contain grid. on select i want to close this load template page. and pass the text data back to previous page. which will display this template into text field. so that user can use saved templates.

How to do this using Asp.Net

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using JavaScript, assuming the template selection window is opened with a call to window.open(). When the template is selected you can communicate and invoke methods (such as passing back the selected template ID) with code similar to this:

```
window.opener.templateSelected(selectedTemplateID);
window.close();
```

Here is information about [window.opener](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_opener.asp)

Answer (score 0):

I believe that [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/passingvalueschild2parent.aspx) may be what you're looking for. It's pretty straight forward and is in C#. It is done in .Net as opposed to client side JS.